# awk for-loop syntax for isolating rows

Tags: for-loop, awk

I have an input file that looks like this:

```
1   Gene1   0.4     0.0009
2   Gene2   0.0003  0.00004
3   Gene3   0.04    0.9
4   Gene4   0.0009  0.00002
5   Gene5   0.8     0.00003
```

And I wish to isolate the rows in which the third ($3) and fourth ($4) fields are less than or equal to 0.01,

I used:

```
awk -F"\t" '{ if ($3<=0.01 && $4<=0.01) print $0 }' input
```

and it worked fine, but I want to do this using a awk for loop because my actual file contains fifteen such fields and I don't want type each field into the above code.

I tried:

```
awk -F"\t" '{ for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) if (i<=0.01) print $0 }' input
```

but it didn't work. I am not good with awk for loop syntax so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Your first `awk` command prints a line only if _both_ columns are `<0.01`.  The second version prints the line if _any_ of the columns have a value less than `0.01`.  Which logic do you want in the final version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of field `i` is `$i`.  Thus, replace:

```
awk -F"\t" '{ for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) if (i<=0.01) print $0 }' input
```

With:

```
awk -F"\t" '{ for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) if ($i<=0.01) print $0 }' input
```

The above however will print multiple copies of the same line.  If you don't want that:

```
$ awk '{f=0; for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) if ($i<=0.01)f=1;} f' input
1   Gene1   0.4     0.0009
2   Gene2   0.0003  0.00004
4   Gene4   0.0009  0.00002
5   Gene5   0.8     0.00003
```

The final `f` in the above command is `awk` shorthand for print the line if `f` is non-zero.

The above applies `or` logic.  Your original code uses `and` logic.  To use `and` logic and print only if all columns have values less than or equal to 0.01, then try:

```
$ awk '{f=1; for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) if ($i>0.01)f=0;} f' input
2   Gene2   0.0003  0.00004
4   Gene4   0.0009  0.00002
```

Alternatively, this does the same but only uses the `<=` test:

```
$ awk '{f=1; for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) f = f && ($i<=0.01);} f' input
2   Gene2   0.0003  0.00004
4   Gene4   0.0009  0.00002
```

Comment: You could also use next `awk '{for(i=3; i<=NF; i++)if($i>0.01)next}1'`

Comment: Hi guys, these codes work great, thanks! I'm just having a bit of trouble understanding the meaning of the syntax: If I want to keep values that are less than or equal to 0.01, why is $i>0.01 in the code? Thanks again.

Comment: @rish  If you want to print rows for which _all values are less than or equal_ to 0,01, then, by the laws, of logic, that means that you want to print rows for which _no value is greater than_ 0.01.  That is how the `$i>0.01` got in the code.  If you prefer it, I just added a version which uses only `<=` tests.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you want to print the line if ALL fields have a given value or one of the fields does or some other combination but something like this would work either way:

```
awk '
{
    cnt = 0
    for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) {
        cnt += (($i)+0 <= 0.01 ? 1 : 0)
    }
}
cnt { print "at least one true:", $0 }
cnt == (NF-3) { print "all true:", $0 }
' file
```

I added the `+0` to force a numeric comparison and I made it a ternary expression just for clarity vs simply using the result of the comparison.